# init script to move file and reboot

Tags: kernel, initramfs, init

I need a tiny init script which get arguments from `/proc/cmdline` and then move or copy dirs or files passed to in via `/proc/cmdline` and reboot.

Everything is fine, except `/sbin/reboot` does not work and `exec /sbin/reboot` make kernel panic instead of reboot. How to reboot in `/init`?

Comment: what kind of init system do you use?

Comment: is your initramfs custom made? based on busybox? and is your /sbin/reboot then the busybox variant or something else? did you try `reboot -f`? if nothing else helps, you can also go through `/proc/sysrq-trigger`